# Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newQuery() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel

Receiving the error (in title) that happens whenever i run the following code:

SearchController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
   {
   $distances = DB::table('posts')->select('distance')->distinct()->get()->pluck('distance');
   $prices = DB::table('posts')->select('price')->distinct()->get()->pluck('price');

   $post = Post::newQuery();

    if ($request->has('price')) {
    $post->where('price', $request->price);
    }

  if ($request->has('distance')) {
   $post->where('distance', $request->distance);
   }

   return view('Pages.search', [
    'distances' => $distances,
    'prices' => $prices,
    'posts' => $post->get()
   ]);
```

Comment: It should work with `$post = Post::query()`; haven't seen the `newQuery()` method before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`query();`

```
 $post = Post::query();
```

Comment: awesome so i have done that, now i press submit, nothing appears and the functionality does not work

Comment: Please mark as verified this answer if its help for you@codingkid

Comment: please change your submit event.